# Java Hashmap Iteration: Look at two values at once?

Tags: java, comparison, loops, hashmap

I have this loop:

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: collection.entrySet()) {

 }
```

I'd like to compare `entry` and the next one after that. How would I do it?

Comment: If you're using HashMap, you need to bear in mind that it doesn't preserve insert-order. If you need the insert-order then you need to use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @Tom: sorted maps don't preserve input order per se - they preserve sort order, which is often a different thing, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it on the previous one.

```
Map.Entry<Integer, String> previous = null;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : collection.entrySet()) {
  if (previous != null) {
    // compare entry to rpevious
  }
  previous = entry;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you loop over you could set a variable called oldEntry for example (initialized to null) and use that in the way you want.

```
 Map.Entry<Integer,String> oldEntry = null;
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: collection.entrySet()) {
   if (oldEntry != null) doStuff(oldEntry, newEntry);
   oldEntry = entry;
 }
```

Comment: I wonder if that is forcing a use of the posh for loop, and that we should drop to using iterators instead.

Comment: when would one use an iterator instead of a loop?